# usage of their for singular

Tags: grammar

This is from a lesson at the [Englishtown website](http://www.englishtown.com/community/channels/lesson2.aspx?ptn=memb&hash=bGVzc29uX2lkPTY1NiZ0YWI9MSZwdG49bm9uZSZzaWQ9MTk4MDE1NTImbGlkPTY1NiZlZD0yMDE0LTExLTEyVDE3JTNhMzAlM2EwMCZjdHI9dWsmbG5nPWVuJmNjPSZldGFnPUUxMTM4ODBfbWVtYiZlZXZlcj000&etag=E113880_memb&eever=4).

**The stove should be positioned so a person using it doesn't have their back facing a doorway.**

Why in the above sentence there is "their" instead of "he" or "she"?

Comment: Similar question on ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192/is-it-correct-to-use-their-instead-of-his-or-her

Comment: I guess there is a typing mistake. when I listened the voice carefully. I guess I heard "that" not "their". by the way how can someone erase his question?

Comment: Simply put, "their" is gender-neutral, meaning that it represents "he" or "she" equally well.  This is a fairly common usage.

Comment: There is no typo; the narrator in fact says "their". *They/them/their* is common in speech with singular antecedents of indefinite gender, and is gradually gaining acceptance even in quite formal written contexts.

Comment: This question has been edited. How can I choose the edited version?